# Why I am getting an error when running the vif() function in R?

Tags: r, correlation, diagnostics

I am checking multicollinearity for my data and am using 3 tests which are Spearman correlation, the condition number and Variance Information Factors (VIF). When I am trying to run the VIF code in R and error is being prompted.

I have managed to run the Spearman correlation and condition number and have removed highly correlated variables where the `r-value` with a cut-off of 0.3. Next I have tried to check the vif of every variable using the the `vif()` function in `R`.

```
Data <- read.csv("Data.csv")
names(Data)
attach(Data)
dim(Data)

sapply(Data,class)

#selecting explanatory variables
DataRed <- Data[,c(4:8,10:73)]
dim(PrepaidMatRed)
#setting my data as a data frame
DataDF <- data.frame(DataRed,row.names = NULL,check.rows = FALSE,check.names = TRUE)

VIF <- vif(DataDF)
```

The expected out is to have a VIF value for all variable but I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
Error in vcov.default(mod) : 
there is no vcov() method for models of class data.frame
```

Comment: There is no need to use attach() `fortunes::fortune(379)`

Comment: First argument of vif is `a fitted model object, typically. Sometimes also a summary() object of such a fitted model.`, not a dataframe

Comment: @Clemsang - so you are saying that I have to fit for example the BLR and then check the VIF?

Comment: Exactly, fit a model first